# Neural Network using Keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

Can someone help me translating this simple neural network using keras.Sequential()?
[image]

I basically want to know how I can define a neural network that has 3 individual input nodes for each node of the next layer (instead of every node of the first layer connecting to each node of the second layer).
I also don't know how the array for the training data should be shaped.

Comment: does it have to be sequential or can it be with the functional api?

Comment: This network is not sequential, so it can only be implemented using the functional API

Comment: I'm voting to close this. OP needs a tutorial and the documentation, which Stack Overflow isn't meant to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://keras.io/models/model and https://keras.io/layers/merge/

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Concatenate

a0 = Input(shape=(3,))
a1 = Input(shape=(3,))
a2 = Input(shape=(3,))
a3 = Input(shape=(3,))

b0 = Dense(1)(a0)
b1 = Dense(1)(a1)
b2 = Dense(1)(a2)
b3 = Dense(1)(a3)

b_concat = Concatenate(axis=-1)([b0, b1, b2, b3])

c = Dense(1)(b_concat)

model = Model(inputs=[a0, a1, a2, a3], outputs=[c])

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd')

model.summary()
```

Gives :

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 3)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 3)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_3 (InputLayer)            [(None, 3)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_4 (InputLayer)            [(None, 3)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 1)            4           input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            4           input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            4           input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            4           input_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 4)            0           dense[0][0]                      
                                                                 dense_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 dense_2[0][0]                    
                                                                 dense_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            5           concatenate[0][0]                
==================================================================================================
Total params: 21
Trainable params: 21
Non-trainable params: 0
```

But this kind of model (without activation function here) is very simple and maybe a "classic" machine learning method could be simpler to implement (see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning).